# Wildfly 17 enabling JMX remote on the same server gives logmanager errors

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, fix-protocol, datadog

I’m looking to enable JMX to allow datadog to monitor our java JBoss wildfly systems but keep hitting runtime errors

I have set up the standalone.xml with

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">              
            <expose-resolved-model/>                     
            <expose-expression-model/>                           
            <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="true"/>                       
</subsystem>
```

And

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
</interface>
```

As well as

```
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
```

Then in my startup.sh i have added

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
```

But this gives me

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly
>   installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system
>   property to "org.jboss.logmanage r.LogManager")

This seems to be fairly common if I look at both here and on google but there seem to be different solutions depending on the version of wildfly.

I think I need to do something like
Set at the start of the standalone.conf

```
JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.logmanager"
```

And then

```
JBOSS_HOME="/opt/wildfly"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.1.11.Final.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/log4j/logmanager/main/log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.2.0.Final.jar"
```

At the end.

But I still get errors “Could not load Logmanager "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"”

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `com.sun.management.jmxremote` or adding the log manager to the boot class path. You'd need to expose the management interface to a remote IP address. That said you shouldn't have the `-Xbootclasspath/p` defined twice.

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: By default, remote JMX is enabled on the management endpoint of WildFly server, No need to add `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` args

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when I upgrade Wildfly server version from 10.1 to 24.0.0 and I resolved it using the below changes.

The below `JAVA_OPTS` changes are required to be added at the end of the `standalone.conf` file

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/a:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/common/main/wildfly-common-1.5.4.Final.jar -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager -Xbootclasspath/a:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.1.18.Final.jar  -Xbootclasspath/a:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/log4j/logmanager/main/log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.2.0.Final.jar"

# Enable jmx remote management
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4447 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false  -Dsun.util.logging.disableCallerCheck=true  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false"
```

**NOTE:** wildfly-common-.jar, jboss-logmanager-.jar, log4j-jboss-logmanager-.jar dependencies should be added to classpath using `-Xbootclasspath/a`

Answer (score 0):

Use the supplied jconsole.sh script in bin, don't try and build up the classpath by hand. You also need to use the custom service url. See the docs for details

Answer (score 0):

change in  standalone.sh: #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash

then

in standalone.conf :

```
JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.logmanager,jdk.nashorn.api,com.sun.crypto.provider,$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS"
```

...

```
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

...

```
BOOT_CP=()
BOOT_CP=("$(find $JBOSS_HOME/modules -type f -name "jboss-logmanager-*.jar")")
BOOT_CP+=("$(find $JBOSS_HOME/modules -type f -name "wildfly-common*.jar")")
for f in $(find $JBOSS_HOME/modules -type f -name "javax.json-*.jar"); do
    BOOT_CP+=("$f")
done
x="-Xbootclasspath/a"
for p in "${BOOT_CP[@]}"; do
    x+=":$p"
done
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Dsun.util.logging.disableCallerCheck=true $x $JAVA_OPTS"
```

it is work but I have still some issues...